# Issue occured in the Resident load 'Table not found'

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

in Tab1

details of `PS1_VBRK` table load is perfectly fine

in Tab5:

```
//ZBI0 - NAST

Left Join(PS1_VBRK)

PS1_NAST_ZBI0:
LOAD
ERDAT as ZBI0_Created_On,
ERUHR as ZBI0_Created_At,
KSCHL as ZBI0_Type,
OBJKY as Billing_doc,
VSTAT as ZBI0_Status
FROM
$(SAPPath_New)$(SAPPrefix_New)NAST.qvd
(qvd)
WHERE KSCHL = 'ZBI0';

RIGHT JOIN(PS1_NAST_ZBI0)

NoConcatenate
LOAD
MAX(ZBI0_Created_On) as ZBI0_Created_On,
MAX(ZBI0_Created_At) as ZBI0_Created_At,
ZBI0_Type,
Billing_doc
RESIDENT PS1_NAST_ZBI0
GROUP BY ZBI0_Type, Billing_doc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you gave the table a name (`PS1_NAST_ZBI0`) Qlik will not produce such table, because you are also joining it to `PS1_VBRK` (`Left Join(PS1_VBRK)`)

So technically table name `PS1_NAST_ZBI0` never existed (as separate table) but it's data is part of `PS1_VBRK`